# How to filter udp flood on dedicated machine

Tags: linux, firewall, udp

someone has any technique to prevent UDP floods or somehow filter them? It's being a big issue because it can't be traffic limited, so delaying UDP packets will not work. Please if someone has anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a hosted box and getting hit with malicious UDP traffic, the only way to mitigate that is upstream with your provider or run your hosting through Cloudflare. They have vast resources available to mitigate that kind of stuff.

Otherwise, if all you're trying to do is ignore UDP traffic on a large LAN subnet or something, you could try just dropping the traffic with iptables. Sometimes (poorly written) services will fill up your syslog and create an I/O bottleneck as they log the nonsense packets from NetBIOS or printer traffic. This technique doesn't work for large scale attacks because if your server is saturated, layer 1 stuff upstream probably is too.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/how-to-mitigate-udp-flood-attacks